# How to update data in Active Directory using DirectoryEntry?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry

I want to update user expire date in Active Directory. If already have user then update expire date. I try to call `CommitChanges` with this code:

```
if (result == null)
{
    DirectoryEntry newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + fNm, "user");
    newUser.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = uNm;
    newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = fNm;
    newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = lNm;
    newUser.Properties["displayName"].Value = NID_Number;

    dateEng = DateTime.Today.AddDays(3); ;

    newUser.Properties["accountExpires"].Value = dateEng.ToFileTime().ToString();

    newUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Add(uNm + "@pkru.ac.th");
    newUser.CommitChanges();
    oGUID = newUser.Guid.ToString();

    const int UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT = 0x0200;
    const int UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = 0x10000;
    newUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT + UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD;
    newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { NID_Number });

    newUser.CommitChanges();

    dirEntry.Close();
    newUser.Close();
}
else
{
    gp = SearchUserGroup(result);

    if (string.Equals(gp, "ABC"))
    {
        dateEng = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7); ;
        DirectoryEntry newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + fNm, "user");
        newUser.Properties["accountExpires"].Clear();
        newUser.Properties["accountExpires"].Value = dateEng.ToFileTime().ToString();
        newUser.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

When I run it show error like this.

> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges()
>   at NIDCardCS.Form1.AddToAD(String fNm, String lNm, String uNm, String) in C:\Users\Test\Form1.cs:line 289
>   Exception thrown: 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException' in System.DirectoryServices.dll
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80071392): The object already exists.

How to update data in Active Directory using `DirectoryEntry` ?

Comment: Did you actually **read** the error message?? What is not clear about **The object already exists.** .....

Comment: Should I delete object and create user again?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the path to the user, use `DirectorySearcher` to find the user.  If you do know the path, construct a new instance using. e.g.,

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=first last,OU=blah,DC=blah"))
{
    entry.Properties["accountExpires"].Value = blah
    entry.CommitChanges()
}
```

You don't normally need to `Clear` a value before setting it.

Always use `using` if you can as it reduces the change of you forgetting to call `Close`.